# Chrome javascript pop up window has a wrong dimension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to open up a new window for a chat room on our site. I have the chat room's dimension set to 750px x 590px. This is the link I have to open up the javascript pop up.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://gamersunite.coolchaser.com/message/gu_chat','gu_chat','width=750,height=590')">open chat window</a>
```

All of the browsers look fine even on IE (screenshot http://grab.by/5qEj) but Chrome opens a window that is a little smaller which causes the scrollbar to appear (screenshot http://grab.by/5qEg)

I googled for a long time but am unable to find the solution. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be fixed by not setting fixed width for the body. (width: auto or better width:100%).

Comment: I didn't set the style `width` in body at all, and yet had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Certainly a bug. I just had the same issue on Chrome 5 and discovered that setting `left` or `top` forces Chrome to use the specified `width`.